# Jasmine - expected parameter

Tags: jasmine

This is my first time looking at Jasmine and TDD in general. I am experimenting with Jasmine at the minute and I have written a function which simply console logs a passed in parameter. I am then writing a test which ensures the function is called with the necessary parameter.

```
describe("Get suggestions function", function(){
    it("Should have parameter - value", function(){
        expect(getSuggestions).toThrow();
    });
});
```

The above code passes in Jasmine's specrunner, but I am unsure if this is the correct method of testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toHaveBeenCalledWith function in Jasmine to get this working.

You'll need to spy on the getSuggestions function and then do something like

```
it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
    expect(getSuggestions).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foobar');
  });
```